# Work Around Internet Explorer Table Render Bug with Small Widths with Flexbox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, flexbox

I have been trying to use a Flexible Box approach for an interface to my application. Almost all has worked sufficiently, but I have encountered a particular bug that really bothers some of my users.

When a user is viewing the data in Internet Explorer 11, in a small window, IE does not display the cells within a table (not a DIV element with a `display: table-cell;`, but elements within an actual TABLE element) correctly. In some circumstances, IE will render table cells with different heights than other cells in the same row. I have simulated this environment [in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e4LL498/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grid Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
div.Sizer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 333px;
    width: 444px;
}

div.Wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

div.ScrollWrap {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.ScrollWrap .Contents {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.Contents td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Sizer">
            <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="ScrollWrap">
                    <table class="Contents">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>0 - F2 aaaaa aaaa</td><td>0 - F3 aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</td><td>0 - F4 aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td><td>0 - F5 aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>1 - F2 aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td><td>1 - F3 aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td><td>1 - F4 aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td><td>1 - F5 aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>2 - F2 aaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaa</td><td>2 - F3 aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaa aaa</td><td>2 - F4 aaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa</td><td>2 - F5 aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>3 - F2 aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa</td><td>3 - F3 aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td><td>3 - F4 aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td><td>3 - F5 aaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>4 - F2 aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa</td><td>4 - F3 aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa</td><td>4 - F4 aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa</td><td>4 - F5 aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>5 - F2 aaaaa aaaaa</td><td>5 - F3 aaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaa</td><td>5 - F4 aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa</td><td>5 - F5 aaaa aaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>6 - F2 aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td><td>6 - F3 aaa aaaa aaaaaa</td><td>6 - F4 aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa</td><td>6 - F5 aaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>7 - F2 aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa</td><td>7 - F3 aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa</td><td>7 - F4 aaa aaaa</td><td>7 - F5 aaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>8 - F2 aaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td><td>8 - F3 aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td><td>8 - F4 aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td><td>8 - F5 aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>a</td><td>9 - F2 aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaa</td><td>9 - F3 aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaa</td><td>9 - F4 aaa aaaaa</td><td>9 - F5 aaaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have found that my particular sample seems to display correctly if I remove one of the wrapper DIV elements, but unfortunately, I don't have a high degree of control over the HTML output, since I am using 3rd-party tools. Thus, I am wondering if a CSS workaround exists to counter this oddity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the root cause is, but looks like an bug or conflict with `cellpadding`. Adding `td { padding: 0; }` (or some explicit value, like `5px`) or changing the table tag to `<table class="Contents" cellpadding="0">` seems to take care of it. https://jsfiddle.net/6e4LL498/1/

```css
div.Sizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 333px;
  width: 444px;
}

div.Wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

div.ScrollWrap {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ScrollWrap .Contents {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.Contents td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="Sizer">
  <div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="ScrollWrap">
      <table class="Contents">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>0 - F2 aaaaa aaaa</td>
            <td>0 - F3 aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</td>
            <td>0 - F4 aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>0 - F5 aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>1 - F2 aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>1 - F3 aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td>
            <td>1 - F4 aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>1 - F5 aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>2 - F2 aaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaa</td>
            <td>2 - F3 aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaa aaa</td>
            <td>2 - F4 aaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa</td>
            <td>2 - F5 aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>3 - F2 aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>3 - F3 aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>3 - F4 aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td>
            <td>3 - F5 aaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>4 - F2 aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>4 - F3 aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>4 - F4 aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>4 - F5 aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>5 - F2 aaaaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>5 - F3 aaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaa</td>
            <td>5 - F4 aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa</td>
            <td>5 - F5 aaaa aaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>6 - F2 aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td>
            <td>6 - F3 aaa aaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>6 - F4 aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa</td>
            <td>6 - F5 aaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>7 - F2 aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>7 - F3 aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>7 - F4 aaa aaaa</td>
            <td>7 - F5 aaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>8 - F2 aaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaa</td>
            <td>8 - F3 aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>8 - F4 aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa</td>
            <td>8 - F5 aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>9 - F2 aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaa</td>
            <td>9 - F3 aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaa</td>
            <td>9 - F4 aaa aaaaa</td>
            <td>9 - F5 aaaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't solve everything, but I did add some client-side script to apply the `cellpadding` attribute on Load and it seemed to help. So, I don't think I should accept this as an answer, but still a +1 from me.

Comment: @palswim fair enough. What issues are you still seeing? I didn't see any weird padding or sizing issues after adding `cellpadding="0"` to the table.